# Draw real time data graph with Highcharts

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, ajax, highcharts

My json data array is as below:

```
[{"item":"Mango","price":30.0,"date":"Feb 18, 2016 6:54:49 PM"},{"item":"karela","price":45.0,"date":"Feb 20, 2016 3:39:08 PM"},{"item":"karela","price":455.0,"date":"Feb 24, 2016 3:59:28 PM"},{"item":"karela","price":65.0,"date":"Feb 29, 2016 10:46:16 AM"},{"item":"karela","price":45.0,"date":"Feb 29, 2016 10:47:05 AM"},{"item":"iphone","price":300.0,"date":"Mar 2, 2016 3:32:14 PM"}]
```

I want to set the "price" as Y-Axis data and "date" as X-Axis data in Highcharts.
This above array generated from a MySQL database.

The above array updates when new data will come and when new data will come then I want to update my graph with new data every time.
For that I am using Ajax.

And one more thing if my time interval is 1 second, then graph also display with nice look.

Comment: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update

Comment: I have checked that but how to set my json array in this that i don't know.
And i don't know Highcharts plugin.

Comment: You need to use data-format required by Highcharts, see [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series<line>.data). In short, loop over all your points and generate proper format, something like this: `$.each(myJSON, function(i, point) { mySeriesData.push([new Date(point.date).getTime(), point.price]; });`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dynamic highcharts with json data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444001/dynamic-highcharts-with-json-data)

Answer (score 2):

Create a websocket program at backend and connect to that socket using the HTML 5 feature websocket use following code .Its a powerful dynamic code i wrote after that i dropped it ,because of license issue.High chart is not a free licence one

```
$('#Chart').highcharts('StockChart',  {
        colors: ["#DDDF0D", "#7798BF", "#55BF3B", "#DF5353", "#aaeeee", "#ff0066", "#eeaaee",
                 "#55BF3B", "#DF5353", "#7798BF", "#aaeeee"],
        chart: {
            //type: 'areaspline',
                     events: {
                    load: function () {

                        // set up the updating of the chart each second

                        var series1 = this.series[0];


                        var webSocket = 
                            new WebSocket('ws://'+Config.ip+':'+Config.port+'/websocket');

                        webSocket.onerror = function(event) {
                            alert(event.data);
                        };

                        webSocket.onopen = function(event) {
                            webSocket.send($scope.IDSelected);
                            return false;
                        };

                        webSocket.onmessage = function(event) {
                            var point = JSON.parse(event.data);
                            var dataPoint1 ={
                                    x:(new Date()).getTime(),
                                    y: Math.round(point.point1),
                                    color:'#00ff00',
                                    segmentColor :'#00ff00',
                                     real_valueMap : Math.round(point.point1)
                                }

                            series1.addPoint(dataPoint1);

                        };

                    }


                     } },
        title: {
            text: "Title"
        } 
        xAxis: {
           type:"datetime",
            plotBands: [{ // visualize the weekend
                from: 4.5,
                to: 6.5,
                color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, .2)'
            }]
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Percentage'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            valueSuffix: ' units'
        }, 
        plotOptions: {
            areaspline: {
                fillOpacity: 0.5
            },
            spline: {
                turboThreshold: 2000}
        },
        series: [{
            marker: {
                states: {
                  hover: {
                    fillColor: {}
                  }
                }
              },
            type: 'coloredline',
            name: 'GraphName1',
            data: (function () {
                // generate an array of random data
                var data = [];
                return data;
            }())

        } ]
    });
```